# DJango queryset filter with a foreign key of a different model

Tags: python, django, orm

I am a beginner in DJango ORM and I want to make a queryset as follows

This is the model that I have made:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=job_type)
    recruter_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    objects = JobManager()

class StudentApplication(models.Model):
    job_fk = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    student_fk = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In this recruiter can list the job posting and data will be feed in `Job` Model, and student can apply to the job and that data will be feed in `StudentApplication` model, with student ID and Job ID as a foreign key.(I have a user model with `user_type=1` for student and `user_type=2` for recruiter)
Now I want to make the query in which I want to show Recruiter the data, that which student have applied for which job posted by him.

In the SQL, query will be:

```
select * from StudentApplication as SA
left join Job as j on j.id = sa.job_fk
where j.recruiter_id = logged_in_user
```

How can I do similar thing using ORM of DJango?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for student applications to a recruiter's job postings as follow:

```
# Retrieve a recruiter from `User` data model
$ recruiter = User.objects.get(email=<recuiter-email>)
# Now, Query student applications to our recruiter's job postings
$ student_applications = StudentApplication.objects.filter(job_fk__recruter_id=recruiter)
```

Hope it helps.